# Deduce P(L), P(PS1|L), P(PS3|OT)

Tags: probability

PS1 handles 60% of business's parcels and has late delivery 5% of the time. PS2 handles 30% of business's parcels and has late deliver 3% of the time. PS3 handles 10% and is late 1% of the time.
My question is how do you find:

1.) Probability of package arrives late.

2.) Probability of a package arrives late and it is from PS1.

3.) if package arrives on-time probability it was PS3.

Edit: My attempt

From the information, I calculated that:
is PS1 handles .60 of total packages then 0.57 are on time and only 0.03 are late. PS2 would have 0.21 packages on time, 0.07 packages late. PS3 has 0.09 on time and 0.01 late.

1.) So probability of late = P(L) = P(ps1_L) + (ps2_L) + (ps3_L) = 0.03 + 0.07 + 0.01 = 0.11

2.) P(PS1|L) = 0.03/0.11 = 0.27

3.) P(PS3|OT) = 0.09/0.87 = 0.10?

I calculated 0.87 by adding up all the packages that are one time; i.e. 0.57+0.21+0.09 = 0.87 and 0.09 is from PS3 on time delivery.

Comment: My question is: what have you tried???

Comment: Sorry, i'll add what i've done.

Comment: The answer to #1 is $0.60\cdot0.05+0.30\cdot0.03+0.10\cdot0.01=4\%$.

Comment: The answer to #2 is $0.60\cdot0.05=3\%$.

Comment: The answer to #3 is $\frac{0.60\cdot(1-0.05)}{0.60\cdot(1-0.05)+0.30\cdot(1-0.03)+0.10\cdot(1-0.01)}=59.375\%$.